# Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo while install delorean for hubspot lib in airflow

Tags: python, docker, airflow, hubspot

I install airflow using docker compose from [official site](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html).
Airflow returns import Error:

```bash
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/extract__hubspot.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/EtlLib/util/transfer/providers/hubspot_conn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hubspot import Client;
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hubspot/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from delorean import Delorean
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delorean'
```

But when I tried to install delorean in containers, it failed with:

```bash
 gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory: 'gcc'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**Q: how to install this library?**

Comment: so you just did `curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/docker-compose.yaml'` and then `docker compose up` ?

Comment: Exactly, after it I download Hubspot and another libs for consumers & providers